# Unable to have dictionary as Datasource of my DropDownList because Dictionary is not IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, enums, dropdown, datasource, ienumerable

I'm having a dictionary that looks like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<Kpi>> KpiGroupDropDown { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<Kpi>>();
```

[image]

Now I want to feed my DropDown with this datasource so the DropDown shows the "Keys" of the dictionary, therefore I use this code:

```
<SfDropDownList TValue="string"
        TItem="Dictionary<string, List<Kpi>>"
        DataSource="@KpiGroupDropDown"
        @bind-Value="@SelectedGroupChartType"
        CssClass="custom-dropdown"
        Width="100px">
        <DropDownListEvents TValue="string" ValueChange="@OnChartTypeSelected" />
        <DropDownListFieldSettings Text="Name" />
</SfDropDownList>
```

However this is giving me this error:

[image]

Does anyone know what Im doing wrong?

**UPDATE according to Alonso's tip**:

Changed my DataSource to KeyValuePair:

```
//Original DataSource
public Dictionary<string, List<Kpi>> KpiGroupDropDown { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<Kpi>>();

//Original DataSource converted to KeyValuePair
List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Kpi>>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Kpi>>>();
```

Looks like this:

[image]

So it is still correct, The list contains 3 items (Keys -> the List with Kpi's).

Code of my SF DropDownList:

```
<SfDropDownList TValue="string"
                            TItem="KeyValuePair<string, List<Kpi>>"
                            DataSource="@list"
                            @bind-Value="@SelectedGroupChartType"
                            CssClass="custom-dropdown"
                            Width="100px">
               <DropDownListEvents TValue="string" ValueChange="@OnChartTypeSelected" />
               <DropDownListFieldSettings Text="Key" />
</SfDropDownList>
```

What I need to do now is to set the right values in "TItem", "TValue".

What I'm trying to achieve:

The Keys (for example "Propulsion") as selectables in the dropdownlist, once selected the Keys + References (for example "Propulsion" -> List with KPI's) needs to be passed into my onchange method:

```
private void OnChartTypeSelected(Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.ChangeEventArgs<string> args)
{

}
```

Does anyone know what I have to put at "TItem", "TValue", and the expected type of my onchange method (currently )?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Screen shoot of error make it difficult to google the error. It will be harder for future viewer to find the question.  Simple copy past may also be quicker and more convenient for you. As it's easy to crop, change data to, anonymise etc.

Comment: As you can see from the dictionary documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) (F1). 
It does implement `IEnumerable`. The error message that that it was expecting a collection of dictionary and only got one.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make the `string` keys of your `Dictionary<string, List<Kpi>>` available, bind to `KpiGroupDropDown.Keys`. This will return an `IEnumerable<string>` with all your keys. If you want to reference the values as well, there is a little more work involved, or you could just access them by their string index:

```cs
List<Kpi> myValue = KpiGroupDropDown["MyIndexPos"];
```

Comment: Hi, I want to pass the entire reference values aswell to another class. Its done by the onchange method of the dropdown: 

    private void OnChartTypeSelected(Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.ChangeEventArgs<string> args)
    {
        
    }

So how can i achieve it that way?

So I kind of want to see the key + all references in the args.

Comment: I don't know how the `SfDropDownList` works. Does it accept dictionaries as data source? And can it handle enumerables a s value?

Comment: I think it can, heres an example:

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/155658/how-to-bind-dictionarystring-string

Answer (score 0):

According to link, [SfDropDownList](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/dropdown-list/getting-started/)

you should set TValue and TItem.
I haven't use the library before.
You need to test if TValue or TItem support List type

Comment: according to the error message, try to convert Dictionary to List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Kpi>>> then assing list source to see if help

Comment: I just did, error is now fixed but I cant find the right settings for the DropDownList, such as: TValue, Titem, what do I need to set there? My DataSource now looks like this:

 List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Kpi>>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Kpi>>>();

Comment: it seems that the datasource support list type but dictionary type

Comment: Give me one minute, Ill update the post to make my issues more clear.

Comment: try to set Value of DropDownListFieldSettings as samples did

Comment: U mean Tvalue="@KpiGroupDropDown"?

public Dictionary<string, List<Kpi>> KpiGroupDropDown { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<Kpi>>();

Comment: No one? Still havent found a solution